# C++ Type Casting: error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'short *' to 'DCTBLOCK'

Tags: c++, type-conversion, casting

I have this types:

```
typedef short DCTELEM;
typedef DCTELEM DCTBLOCK[64];
```

Array of last type and a pointer to a malloc'ed array of shorts:

```
DCTBLOCK MQUAD;
short * ptrArray;
```

I need MQUAD to bet to specific location pointed to by ptrArray;

In C I would prolly write something like

```
MQUAD = ptrArray + 3 * 2;
```

and have MQUAD after that pointing to a needed location, but I get

> error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'short *' to 'DCTBLOCK'

in c++, cause I know there is a difference in a type of array and a pointer to some-type.

Answer (score 1):

Your `MQUAD` variable is an array, not a pointer, so you can't assign to it (thanks to Remy Lebeau's comment). If you declare it as:

```
DCTELEM *MQUAD;
```

then you can assign to it:

```
MQUAD = reinterpret_cast<DCTELEM *>(ptrArray + 3 * 2);
```

This is using the C++ cast syntax. You can use C cast syntax if you like too.

Comment: MQUAD is an array variable, not a pointer variable. You cannot assign a pointer value to it. If Anton wants MQUAD to point at a location inside the malloc'ed shorts that are being pointed at by the ptrArray variable, then MQUAD has to be declared as a DCTELEM* or short* pointer to begin with.

Comment: Yes, totally rigth, i just realized, 1 mins before openning that window :).

Answer (score 0):

The main mistake is

```
DCTBLOCK MQUAD // it's wrong
DCTELEM* MQUAD // it's right
```

and you may cast as u want

```
MQUAD = ptrArray + 3 * 2;
```